# basis of a matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

In the space $$V = \{ a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3, \space a_i \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ of polynomials of degree $3$ the image phi is $ϕ(f)=-4f' -5f'',$ where $f$ is polynomial and these are his derivatives. Prove that $f$ is a linear operator and find its matrix in the basis {$1,x,x^2,x^3$}.

Proving that is operator is easy: just use the 2 identities. However, how can I find the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of considering each of $1, x, x^2, x^3$ as unit vectors with $1$ in the first, second, third, and fourth place respectively. Since
$$
\phi(1) = 0 \\
\phi(x) = -4 \times 1 \\
\phi(x^2) = -8 \times x - 10 \times 1 \\
\phi(x^3) = -12 \times x^2 - 30 \times x
$$
this means
$$
\phi = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & -4 & -10 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -8 & -30 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -12 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]
$$
which just comes from recording at the $(i, j)$th place how many copies of $x^i$ you get in the expression $\phi(x^j)$ (for $i,j$ starting at $0$).

Comment: Also how can I find the basis of the core? ker ,of the matrix

Comment: Use the definition of the kernel of a matrix. Start with a generic element of your space and suppose it is sent to zero by $\phi$. What condition does this give on its coefficients? This will tell you what elements of your space are needed to span it.

Comment: Well ,I can't really understand their definitions of ker and Im can you explaint them easily?

Comment: Ker is 'kernel', it is the set of things sent to zero by the function. Im is 'image', it is basically the range of the function - the set of all objects you can reach by using it.

Comment: And how is this connected to the rows or columns of the matrix.A row/colum which is all 0 is kernel element?

Comment: A column of zeroes indicates that there *are* things in the kernel, but it is not a kernel element since it is not a vector. Like I said, the kernel consists of all vectors sent to zero. Start with a generic vector $\mathbf{v} = [a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3]$. If it's to be in the kernel of $\phi$, then $\phi(\mathbf{v}) = 0$. Suppose this is the case and solve it all out, then this will give you the right conditions on $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ for $\mathbf{v}$ to be a kernel element.

Comment: Aha so you mean that if we get a column and multply it with the basis if the result is 0's only then the codrinates of v will gives us when $\phi(v)$ is 0